# Windows Phone 8 Receiving raw Push Notification issue

Tags: windows-phone-8, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst, mpns

I am unable to receive raw notification on my WindowsPhone8.

Followed :https://github.com/barryvdh/PushPlugin/#uccb-wp8-only

Able to get toast notification. In my app toggle is happening like below.

> Case 1: If I comment ecb able to get both raw and toast but not
>   channel uri.
>
> Case 2: If I won't comment ecb able to get toast and channel uri but
>   not raw

My code as follows:

```
if (device.platform == "Win32NT") {
        console.log("called");

            pushNotification.register(
                channelHandler,
                errorHandler,
                {
                    "channelName": "channelName",
                    "ecb": onNotificationWP8,
                    "uccb": channelHandler,
                    "errcb": jsonErrorHandler
                });
        }
        else {
            console.log("not called");
        }
    }


function channelHandler(event) {
    var uri = event.uri;
    console.log("UUUUURRRRRRRRRRRIIIIIIIII  :" + uri);
}

function errorHandler(e) {
}

function jsonErrorHandler(error) {
    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li style="color:red;">error:' + error.code + '</li>');
    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li style="color:red;">error:' + error.message + '</li>');
}

function onNotificationWP8(e) {
    console.log("notification called");
    if (e.type == "toast" && e.jsonContent){
        pushNotification.showToastNotification(successHandler, errorHandler,
        {
            "Title": e.jsonContent["wp:Text1"], "Subtitle": e.jsonContent["wp:Text2"], "NavigationUri": e.jsonContent["wp:Param"]
        });
    }

    if (e.type == "raw" && e.jsonContent) {
        alert(e.jsonContent.Body);
    }
}
```

**Tried with error and trail methods. Please suggest what might went wrong.**

Comment: Looks like you are trying Push with a custom plugin and noticing the issue.Do you see issues with a Worklight/MobileFirst project using out of the box , push feature?

Comment: I am using Worklight Version 6.1.0.02-20151114-1310

Comment: How is the issue posted related to Worklight ? Eventhough Push notifications support is available out of the box with Worklight , you are using a custom plugin.
If you use the sample here :
http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/PushNotificationsProject.zip
and not add any custom plugin, are you able to get raw notifications ?

Comment: I am not getting raw notification but able to get toast. I used custom plugin because my requirement is only to get channel uri to send it to back end and handle received notification in client side. I don't wanted to use any adapter. If worklight going to help me with out any ifix thats well and good. The above link that you shared is contains android environment, actually I am expecting windows environment.

Comment: add the WindowsPhone environment

Comment: Thank you Vivin. But am finding difficulty in shared project to achieve what I want exactly. Is there any Worklight API are there to get Channel URI for Windows Phone 8? Is it not possible with out adapter? Do I need to raise PMR for this as well? Feel free to suggest. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it got solved by adding Coding4Fun.Toolkit.Controls.dll

And some code updation in PushPlugin.cs

using Coding4Fun.Toolkit.Controls;
using System.Windows.Threading;

void PushChannel_ShellToastNotificationReceived(object sender, NotificationEventArgs e)
        {

```
        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            string msg = string.Empty;
            foreach (var item in e.Collection)
            {
                if (item.Key == "wp:Text1")
                {
                    msg = item.Value;
                }
            }

            MessageBox.Show(msg, "Notification", MessageBoxButton.OK);

        });
    }
```

My heart-full thanks to Rajith who helped me to make it happen.

Answer (score 0):

The issue observed does not appear to be related to Worklight at all. From the description and the code snippet, you are bypassing Worklight client SDK and server completely , and using a custom Cordova Push plugin. The custom plugin's working in your application should be analyzed to understand the variance in behaviour.

Since you are not using Worklight Push at all, you can try disabling it and check if this helps your case.

To do this, navigate to the config.xml . This will be located in apps/YourAppName/WindowsPhone8/native/Resources folder.

Look for :

```
<feature name="Push">
    <param name="wp-package" value="Push" />
</feature>
```

Change this to:

```
<feature name="Push">
    <param name="wp-package" value="Push" />
    <param name="onload" value="false" />
</feature>
```

On the query regarding Worklight API:

There are no Worklight APIs that return Channel URI. When using Worklight SDK for Push, all this is done automatically and hidden from the user. Even with a Push Adapter in place, it is not possible to obtain the channel URI as there no APIs published to obtain this information.

Comment: Thank you Vivin. Unfortunately disabling Worklight Push didn't helped me in my case. You are correct. Worklight is not stopping me here. Need to figure it out what went wrong in custom plugin.